# how to get list of file from ftp server if server is very slow or there are more clients are there in java

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have to get the list of files or folder present in ftp  server .I have tried the following  code but I do not get the list. If I am running the same code I am getting list of file if I am making my local system as server but when I apply the same code then I am sucessfully logged in and list method of `FTPClient` class is working but `listFiles()`,`listNames()` are not working .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class ListFileOfServerCheck {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException, IOException{

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    ArrayList dirList=new ArrayList();

   client.connect("myserver");
   client.login("vishal", "vishal");
    if(client.isConnected())
        System.out.println("connected");
    int i=0;
    System.out.println("number of files on server="+client.list());
    String[] names = null;
    int itration=1;
    while(names==null){
       System.out.println(itration +"th itration");
       names = client.listNames();
       itration++;
    }
    client.logout();
    client.disconnect();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please read the markdown documentation in order to learn how to format code properly for your next questions, it will be easier for you to get an answer ;)

Comment: Coud you add this: reply = ftp.getReplyCode(); if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) { print something }. See http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: I don't seem to have a client.list(); but a client.listNames() and client.listFiles().

Answer (score 1):

It's question what is your current dir when you log in to the FTP. Try to use:

```
client.listNames("/path/to/the/folder");
```

instead of relying on the current working directory.

It would be also good practice to check what returns the

```
client.login(...)
```